# Кроссмодульные переменные в python 3.8+

Tags: python, python-3.x

искатели (и мудрецы), я столкнулся с необходимостью (в следствие моей любви к упрощению себе жизни) назначения кроссмодульных переменных.

На данный момент после эксперементов в **python 3.10** я знаю следующее:

- При импорте неинициализированных переменных (например, функций, классов, интов и т.д) они не изменяются между модулями, а также путь в памяти у них одинаковый во всех файлах где они импортируются
- Переназначение (и назначение) переменных в импортируемом модуле может быть решением, но как по мне выглядит это нестабильно
- Инициализированные классы и функции это отдельные от неинициализированных объекты (как напоминание, почему в примере класс не инициализирован)

В интернете доходчивых объяснений того, как в этом векторе работает импорт я не нашел (или не повезло с выборкой или катарактой).

Дополнение(для большей доходчивости):
Папка с проектом:

- main.py
- at.py
- bt.py

main.py:

```
import at
print(f'До переназначения от bt.py: {at.A.a}')
at.A.b = 2
import bt

print(f'После переназначения от bt.py: {at.A.a}')
```

bt.py:

```
import at
at.A.a = 3
print(f'После назначения от main.py: {at.A.b}')
```

at.py:

```
class A:
    a = 1
```

Comment: В чем вопрос то?

Comment: @Namerek каким образом организовать кроссмодульные переменные с минимальными затратами усилий и наибольшей стабильностью.

Прошу прощения, забыл конкретно обозначить вопрос, пока уделял внимание примеру

Comment: Опишите изначальную задачу. Сейчас это вопрос ХУ, может вам и не нужны кроссмодульные переменные, а есть другой и более правильный способ сделать то, что вам нужно. Только из вашего описания не ясно ни что вам нужно, ни в чем у вас проблема с этими переменными. Опишите проблему в виде, "вот код, я делаю то-то, получаю то-то, а ожидаю то-то". Но сначала - изначальную задачу.

Comment: Если, к примеру, Вас устроят строковые значения переменных, то можно заюзать переменные окружения

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA я хочу сделать клиент pyrogram глобальным для всех модулей, чтобы избавится от надобности тащить его в те функции, которые выносить в базовую функцию (которая принимает апдейты) не имеет смысла, т.к. есть функции, которые используются для обработки данных из нескольких хендлеров

Comment: Сделайте функцию, создающую клиент pyrogram, навесьте на нее кэширующий декоратор (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache), там где нужно вызывайте эту функцию.